# Thermal Expansion Of Water Vs Air

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Not a physicist, but I would very much appreciate any help with a specific question.

If I have a sealed volume of air and a sealed volume of water that are both the same size, temperature, and initial pressure...

and I impart an equal amount of heat energy to both volumes, would the resulting increased pressure be the same in the two volumes? If not, which would have the greater increase in pressure?

In practical terms, if I have have two sealed 500 mL containers (one with water and one with air [both starting at atmospheric pressure]) and hold a flame under each for 2 minutes, which would have the greater increase in pressure? Would the resulting temperatures be the same for both containers?

Thanks!

Comment: Certainly not. Air for most purposes can be modeled as an ideal gas, therefore the increase in pressure would be found using the ideal gas law. Water, on the other hand, does not behave like an ideal gas. Here's a link with some equations describing it:

https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/fluid-density-temperature-pressure-d_309.html

Answer (score 1):

The change in pressure $P$ for a given change in temperature $T$ at constant volume $V$ can be expressed mathematically as the partial derivative $$\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_V=-\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}\right)_T=\alpha K,$$

where I've used the [triple-product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product_rule) and the definitions of the thermal expansion coefficient $\alpha\equiv\frac{1}{V}\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P$ and bulk modulus $K\equiv-V\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}\right)_T$. These are material properties you can look up for air and water.

For the change in pressure for a given amount of heating $Q$, ignoring the thermal mass of the container, we can use the relation $Q=mc_V\Delta T$, where $m$ is the mass and $c_V$ is the constant-volume specific heat capacity, to obtain

$$\frac{\Delta P}{Q}=mc_V\alpha K=\rho Vc_V\alpha K,$$

where $\rho$ is the density and $V$ is the container volume. The constant-volume specific heat capacity $c_V$ and density $\rho$ are additional material properties that you can look up for air and water. From this, you can find the pressure change for both scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

The temperature rise in each container can be calculated from the equation $Q=mC_v\Delta T$.  Rearranging this equation for the temperature rise, one gets $\Delta T=Q/mC_v$.  For a given volume (let's assume one cubic meter rather than 500 ml), at atmospheric pressure and a temperature of 15 deg C, the air will have a mass of 1.23 kg while the water will have a mass of 1000 kg.  In addition, the air will have a somewhat lower specific heat (aka $C_v$) than the water, meaning that for a given heat input to both containers, the air will experience a much larger temperature rise than the water.

Regarding the heat input to each container, that will depend on the thermal conductivity of each container, the shape of the container, how much area is exposed to the flame, how much heat escapes the container and goes into the environment via convection and radiation, etc., so it's not possible to say how much heat will go into each container without somewhat more information and probably a few experiments.

Regarding the pressure in the air container, the air will act like an ideal gas, so the equation $PV=nRT$ applies.  Solving this equation for pressure gives the equation $P=nRT/V$.  "n" is the number of moles of air in the container, "R" is the universal gas constant, and "V" is the volume of the container.  "n" and "R" are constant, and I assume that the pressure in the air container will not be able to "stretch" the container, making "V" also constant, so it is seen that the pressure in the air container is directly proportional to the absolute temperature (aka "T"), and the pressure rise in the container will be directly proportional to the temperature rise in the container.

Regarding the pressure in the water container, water is relatively incompressible and it will expand upon heating.  Due to this, the pressure in the water container should rise dramatically and that pressure rise should be much higher than in the air container.  The exact pressure rise for this container can't be calculated without somewhat more data, such as the material of construction, the wall thickness, shape, coefficient of thermal expansion, etc.  Also note that if the container's coefficient of thermal expansion is equal to or greater than water, there will not be a pressure rise, so the details really matter for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The thermal expansion coefficients of air and water are:

Air : $\mathrm{0.00369 \ K^{-1}}$

Water : $\mathrm{0.000214 \ K^{-1}}$

And the specific heats are:

Air : $\mathrm{993 \ J/KgK}$

Water: $\mathrm{4190 \ J/KgK}$

A substance with a higher thermal expansion coefficient and lower specific heat would expand in volume faster than another.

We can clearly see that air expands faster because it has the ability to increase volume faster whilst taking less heat.